# What does output of compare-object mean when comparing two files in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The script below comapres two files but im unclear on the understanding output of the sideIndicator arrows and dots below:

... <=

```
 What does the above actually mean ?
```

Here is the comparison script:

```
  Compare-Object -referenceobject (Get-Content C:\Users\admin\Desktop\powershell_scripts\zz.txt) -differenceobject (Get-Content C:\Users\admin\Desktop\powershell_scripts\allstudents5.txt) -SyncWindow 100 -includeequal

AD\zpjnbb                ... <=                                                                   
AD\zhjfhg                ... <=    
                             <=                                    
                             <=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell you can use the `Get-Help` CmdLet to find out more:

```
Get-Help Compare-Object -ShowWindow
```

Straight from the `Description`:

> **Description**
>
> The Compare-Object cmdlet compares two sets of objects. One set of objects is the "reference set," and the other set is the "difference
>   set."
>
> The result of the comparison indicates whether a property value appeared only in the object from the reference set (indicated by the
>   <= symbol), only in the object from the difference set (indicated by
>   the => symbol) or, if the IncludeEqual parameter is specified, in both
>   objects (indicated by the == symbol).
>
> NOTE:  If the reference set or the difference set is null ($null), Compare-Object generates a terminating error.

A small example on the logic:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ('A', 'B') -DifferenceObject ('B','C') -IncludeEqual

InputObject    SideIndicator                                            
-----------    -------------                                            
B              ==                                                       
C              =>                                                       
A              <=
```

For more examples you can try:

```
Get-Help Compare-Object -Examples
```

Comment: thanks but its the "..." before "<=" I dont understand - can you explain what that means ?

Comment: Added an example to the answer. On the three dots you can find more info [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/csps/archive/2011/02/17/powershellthreedots.aspx).